# Flash Carousel showing different images in different browsers

Tags: xml, image, actionscript, joomla

I have a Flash carousel on my website, and I wanted to change one of the images, and delete another icon altogether. I have uploaded the revised XML file, published the new .swf (just in case), and uploaded to my Joomla site.

For some strange reason, its still showing the old icons in Firefox (even though I've deleted these images from the referenced folder), and its showing the new icons in IE, only without the one image I added. Very strange.

I've refreshed, created a new .swf, made sure I've saved the XML file etc but no change

My carousel is on this link - http://www.myramis.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=48&Itemid=54

This is probably one of those amateur mistakes I think, I've thought of everything but drawing a blank at the moment.

Oh i should probably mentioned that the revised carousel has 4 icons, and the old one has 5. The new image I put in has an icon of a jigsaw.

XML File is as follows

```
<icons>

<icon image="icon3.jpg" tooltip="Ramis Software" link="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=57&Itemid=67"/>

<icon image="icon4.jpg" tooltip="Ramis Lite" link="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=56&Itemid=70"/>

<icon image="icon5.jpg" tooltip="Ramis Mobile" link="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=55&Itemid=71"/>

<icon image="jigsaw.jpg" tooltip="Ramis Modules" link="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=55&Itemid=71"/>

</icons>
```

Hope you can help,

Kind Regards,

Snakespan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to clear your cache and temporary internet files to see the new SWF and icons. Refreshing doesn't necessarily load the new SWF if the browser does not think it is new.

Comment: Hi, I've cleared the cache in the Joomla back end with no results unfortunately.

Comment: It looks like you figured out what I meant, but just in case I was talking about the browser cache in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting a carousel with 3 icons, not including a jigsaw.

Comment: yes, as am I on internet explorer but on firefox I'm getting 5 icons which is the old swf.

Answer (score 0):

Is your new icon in the same format as the other ones (JPEG, PNG, GIF)?  Maybe your control doesn't support it.  Is it present on your server, in the right directory?

Can you show the XML you use to configure the control?